# Is there anyway in docusign api to generate a link for completed envelope?

Tags: node.js, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

We are generating two recipient view one for admin and client - they have unique clientUserId for admin its prefixed with `admin-` now when all parties signed the envelope is it possible to generate a new link view which is combination of the client and admin signature im looking for something like the signer view link..  which can also be embedded..?

I've tried using the combine via `getDocument` but this only returns a file and not viewable link.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that the same way you did embedded signing, the same API call, for the specific recipient.

https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node/blob/master/embeddedSigning.js

This is the code for getting the URL:

```
function makeRecipientViewRequest(args) {
  // Data for this method
  // args.dsReturnUrl
  // args.signerEmail
  // args.signerName
  // args.signerClientId
  // args.dsPingUrl

  let viewRequest = new docusign.RecipientViewRequest();

  // Set the url where you want the recipient to go once they are done signing
  // should typically be a callback route somewhere in your app.
  // The query parameter is included as an example of how
  // to save/recover state information during the redirect to
  // the DocuSign signing. It's usually better to use
  // the session mechanism of your web framework. Query parameters
  // can be changed/spoofed very easily.
  viewRequest.returnUrl = args.dsReturnUrl + "?state=123";

  // How has your app authenticated the user? In addition to your app's
  // authentication, you can include authenticate steps from DocuSign.
  // Eg, SMS authentication
  viewRequest.authenticationMethod = "none";

  // Recipient information must match embedded recipient info
  // we used to create the envelope.
  viewRequest.email = args.signerEmail;
  viewRequest.userName = args.signerName;
  viewRequest.clientUserId = args.signerClientId;

  // DocuSign recommends that you redirect to DocuSign for the
  // embedded signing. There are multiple ways to save state.
  // To maintain your application's session, use the pingUrl
  // parameter. It causes the DocuSign signing web page
  // (not the DocuSign server) to send pings via AJAX to your
  // app,
  viewRequest.pingFrequency = 600; // seconds
  // NOTE: The pings will only be sent if the pingUrl is an https address
  viewRequest.pingUrl = args.dsPingUrl; // optional setting

  return viewRequest;
}
```